# request post with python's requests package does not work

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am working with the django framework. I'm trying to send a post request with token using the requests package but it doesn't work. the status code of the request is 200.Here is my code:

```
def modifier_periode_push(request):
    url = "ip_addr/openapi/device"
    option1,option2,option3 = "040A0001","041E0001","043C0001"
    headers = {
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip","Content-Length":"286","Content-Type":"application/json","Token":"xxxxxxxxx",
    "User-Agent":"python-requests/2.26.0"
    }
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST["periode"] == "10":
            payload = convertir_en_hexa(option1)
        elif request.POST["periode"] == "30":
            payload = convertir_en_hexa(option2)
        else:
            payload = convertir_en_hexa(option3)
        data = {
            "devEUI":request.POST["devEUI"],
            "confirmed":False,
            "fPort":int(request.POST["fPort"]),
            "data":payload
        }
        try:
            **req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)**
            print(req.status_code)# returns 200
        except:
            print("Erreur")
        return HttpResponse("ok")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Requete non authorisée")
```

I have got this message `{'code': 1003, 'msg': 'No Token, Please log in again'}`
I want to know why it does not work and how to debug.

Comment: Status code 200 indicates that the request has succeeded. To verify the result you can check in the debugger the response you received to your POST request.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work ? 200 means success, but if you wanna check the result you can use `req.json()` or `req.text`

Comment: I don't see any change in the server. Data has not been posted.

Comment: I modified the request by replacing the data parameter by params. Now it gives me the following error: "('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))"

Comment: What kind of changes do you expect? How can you know the data has not been posted? Finally, couldn't it be a matter of posted data? Did you check your parameters?

Comment: I replaced in requests.post (...) data = data by params = data. I know the data has not been posted because my server has a web interface that allows checking.

Comment: The message you got back tells you why it didn't work.  That page requires a login, and you have not logged in.  Wasn't that obvious?

Comment: But I specified the token in the headers

Comment: Is the token supposed to be in the headers, or in the JSON data?

Comment: This is what documentation says: "When the user invokes the interface, the x- access-token field value in the request header needs to be set to
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, and the token is sent along with the request"

Comment: You didn't set "X-Access-Token".  You set "Token".  Spelling matters.

Comment: Ah yes !!!! Thank you.